# Is there a safe way to call wait() on std::future?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard says:

> 30.6.6 Class template future
>
> (3) "The effect of calling any member function other than the destructor,
>   the move-assignment operator, or valid on a future object for which
>   `valid() == false` is undefined."

So, does it mean that the following code might encounter undefined behaviour?

```
void wait_for_future(std::future<void> & f)
{
    if (f.valid()) {
        // what if another thread meanwhile calls get() on f (which invalidates f)?
        f.wait();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Q1: Is this really a possible undefined behaviour?

Q2: Is there any standard compliant way to avoid the possible undefined behaviour?

Note that the standard has an interesting note [also in 30.6.6 (3)]:

> "[Note: Implementations are encouraged
>   to detect this case and throw an object of type future_error with an
>   error condition of `future_errc::no_state`. —endnote]"

Q3: Is it ok if I just rely on the standard's note and just use `f.wait()` without checking `f`'s validity?

```
void wait_for_future(std::future<void> & f)
{
    try {
        f.wait();
    }
    catch (std::future_error const & err) {
        return;
    }
}
```

### EDIT: Summary after receiving the answers and further research on the topic

As it turned out, the real problem with my example was **not directly** due to parallel modifications (a single modifying `get` was called from a single thread, the other thread called `valid` and `wait` which shall be safe).

The real problem was that the `std::future` object's `get` function was accessed from a different thread, which is not the intended use case! The `std::future` object shall only be used from a single thread!

The only other thread that is involved is the thread that sets the shared state: via return from the function passed to `std::async` or calling `set_value` on the related `std::promise` object, etc.

More: even `wait`ing on an `std::future` object from another thread is not intended behaviour (due to the very same UB as in my example#1). We shall use `std::shared_future` for this use case, having each thread its own copy of an `std::shared_future` object. Note that all these are **not** through the same shared `std::future` object, but through separate (related) objects!

**Bottom line:
These objects shall not be shared between threads. Use a separate (related) object in each thread.**

Comment: Notes are non-normative and shouldn't be relied on. If a `std::future` is accessed by multiple threads, you should apply some sort of external synchronization anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A normal `std::future` is not threadsafe by itself. So yes it is UB, if you call modifying functions from multiple threads on a single `std::future` as you have a potential race condition. Though, calling `wait` from multiple threads is ok as it's const/non-modifying.

However, if you really need to access the return value of a `std::future` from multiple threads you can first call `std::future::share` on the future to get a [`std::shared_future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future) which you can copy to each thread and then each thread can call `get`. Note that it's important that each thread has its own `std::shared_future` object.

You only need to check valid if it is somehow possible that your future might be invalid which is not the case for the normal usecases(`std::async` etc.) and proper usage(e.g.: not callig `get` twice).

Comment: I do not want to call `get` multiple times. The question is whether is it possible that the `future` becomes invalid between a call to `valid` and a call to `wait` (example #1). So: (multiple) threads calling `wait` and a single calling `get`.

Comment: @NorbertBérci Yes, that's a problem as get is modifying. However, without further code I don't see the sense in that kind of usage.

Comment: I had some further research meanwhile and it seems like `std::future` is not supposed to be shared between threads (because it has the UBs like above). I should have used `std::shared_future` for this use case (which means a separate `std::shared_future` object per thread), and this is exactly what you have recommended. I've accepted your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Futures allow you to store the state from one thread and retrieve it from another. They don't provide any further thread safety.

> Is this really a possible undefined behaviour?

If you have two threads trying to get the future's state without synchronisation, yes. I've no idea why you might do that though.

> Is there any standard compliant way to avoid the possible undefined behaviour?

Only try to get the state from one thread; or, if you genuinely need to share it between threads, use a mutex or other synchronisation.

> Is it ok if I just rely on the standard's note

If you known that the only implementations you need to support follow that recommendation, yes. But there should be no need.

> and just use `f.wait()` without checking `f`'s validity?

If you're not doing any weird shenanigans with multiple threads accessing the future, then you can just assume that it's valid until you've retrieved the state (or moved it to another future).

Comment: Please note that I do not want to call `get` multiple times. My use case is: a thread calling `valid` then `wait` and another thread calling `get` meanwhile (example #1). This is all. As it turned out, I should have used `std::shared_future` instead. So the bottom line is that `wait` and `get` is not supported from different threads (acting on the same, shared object).